# Is 2 hours enough connection time in Dusseldorf?

Tags: international-travel, layovers, short-connections, dus

I am flying alone for the first time. I have flight from Serbia to Dusseldorf and I have 2 hour connection time until the next flight to Palma. I'm afraid I'll miss the flight, as I don't know where to go or where to look for my flight.

Is 2 hours enough to do everything I need to do? Do I need to reclaim my luggage when I land in DUS? I'm very nervous.

Comment: I would just say "you should be fine", that's a good connection time!  Dusseldorf is NOT a huge airport, so that's good news.  Huge airports are horrible!

Comment: I will second the comment; I've connected there and it was extremely easy and quick.

Comment: Did you book it in a single booking? If yes, 100%. If not, 99%

Answer (score 1):

If your first flight won't be delayed, two hours are enough time for a connection in Düsseldorf. (You can cross it from Terminal A to Terminal C in less than 15 minutes).

As for your luggage - you have to ask your airline.

Here is the information about flight transfers at the Düsseldorf airport: [Transferring](https://www.dus.com/en/flights/transferring).